# Get bits per each second FFmpeg/Mediainfo

Tags: ffmpeg, bit, bitrate, mediainfo

Is there any way to get how many bits per second are in any video?

ej:

```
ffmpeg/mediainfo -commands input.mkv
```

Result:

```
sec 1 - 500bits
sec 2 - 600bits
sec 3 - 300bits
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can output frame information such as the packet size and time with `ffprobe`:

`ffprobe -show_entries frame=pkt_size,pkt_pts_time <input>`

You can then aggregate them as you like. For eg. the `plotframes` `ffmpeg` tool uses this information to generate a video frame size by type plot.

[image]

Comment: Do you know have a link to a guide on how to download the software and doing this? Thanks mate!

Comment: ffprobe is part of ffmpeg. You can find the source, packages and static builds on http://ffmpeg.org/download.html. There's also a compilation guide

Comment: I have an ffmpeg build with the plotframe tool and can't find any example how to use it. Can it be run from within ffmpeg ?Care to share a working command?

Comment: BTW, this is how to use plotframes: `plotframes -i file.mp4 -t svg -o file.svg`. Assuming you have an ffmpeg build with tools installed and have gnuplot and perl (with JSON module) on your system.

Answer (score 4):

To install on OS X, first install Xcode and [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then:

#### Python

```
brew install python3
pip3 install matplotlib
curl -OLJ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeroepoch/plotbitrate/master/plotbitrate.py
chmod +x plotbitrate.py
./plotbitrate.py -f svg -o out.svg input.mkv
```

#### Pearl

```
brew install cpanm gnuplot
sudo cpanm -v JSON
curl -OLJ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/tools/plotframes
chmod +x plotframes
./plotframes.pl -i input.mkv -o output.svg -t svg
```

Comment: Really awesome!